# How to make highcharts stacked bar chart start from a specific date

Tags: highcharts

How can i make my chart start from year 2010 or more specificly from date 02-02-2010,
i made this chart but i don't know how to continue http://jsfiddle.net/P87XF/2/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['John']
        },
        yAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
              day: '%d-%m-%Y'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar:{
                stacking: 'normal',
                pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 
            }
        },
            series: [{
            name: 'Manager',
            data: [Date.UTC(2014, 20, 01)]
        }, {
            name: 'Developer',
            data: [Date.UTC(2012, 20, 01)]
        }, {
            name: 'Tester',
            data: [Date.UTC(2010, 20, 01)]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little hard for me to understand what is purpose for stacking dates? It feels strange for me, so I have disabled stacking and used column-range type, here is live effect: http://jsfiddle.net/P87XF/3/

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            inverted: true,
            type: 'columnrange'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Stacked bar chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['John']
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: Date.UTC(2010, 1, 2),
            type: 'datetime',
            dateTimeLabelFormats: {
              day: '%d-%m-%Y'
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Total fruit consumption'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            reversed: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar:{
                //stacking: 'normal',
                //pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 
            }
        },
            series: [{
            name: 'Manager',
            data: [[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 2), Date.UTC(2014, 20, 01)]]
        }, {
            name: 'Developer',
            data: [[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 2), Date.UTC(2012, 20, 01)]]
        }, {
            name: 'Tester',
            data: [[Date.UTC(2010, 1, 2), Date.UTC(2010, 20, 01)]]
        }]
    });
});
```